# Loop through making all base 6 numbers of length 25 excluding 0

Tags: vb.net

I need to loop through getting every possible solution for a game and bruteforcing it. I need to get all strings that are 25 characters long and only contain numbers 1 through 5, does anyone have a simple way to do this that doesn't require 25 for loops?

Comment: Really confusing. can you show the code that you just tried towards it.?

Comment: That's the issue, I cannot seem to figure out how to do it, all I need is a collection of strings from '1111111111111111111111111' to '5555555555555555555555555' including only the numbers 1-5.

Comment: If you can go through ten million values per second, it will take a few years ((5^25)iterations/(1E7 iterations/s)/(31557600 s/yr) ≈ 944 years). Perhaps a different approach would be desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does anyone have a simple way to do this that doesn't require 25 for
>   loops?

Not sure of the cost but using a BigInteger type means only needing one loop:

```
Imports System.Numerics.BigInteger

    Dim BadNums As String = "67890"
    Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter("AllNums.txt")
    For I As Numerics.BigInteger = Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("1111111111111111111111111") To Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("5555555555555555555555555")
        Dim temp As String = I.ToString
        Dim index As Integer = temp.IndexOf("6"c)
        If index < 0 Then
            sw.WriteLine(temp)
        Else
            I += 5 * (Pow(10, 24 - index)) - 1
        End If
    Next
    sw.Close()
```

This will short circuit the loop by skipping over values that don't fit.
Each string is written to a text file.

Comment: I can see an easy optimisation: if the last digit is `6` then increment `I` to skip to the next multiple of ten. That should shave a few hundred years off the run time :)

Comment: yep that's what the else block does.  Basically cuts the for loop in half

Comment: Well that's a "Duh!" to me. But can't you just use `Dim index As Integer = temp.IndexOf("6"c)`? It appears to give the same result as your code when tested on the first and last 400 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is ideal for this sort of problem.  I'll give you pseudocode, you can then write the VB.NET:

```
build_number( digit_array, current_digit)
is
    if current_digit = digit_array.length
    then
        call use_number(digit_array)
    else
        loop digit_array[current_digit] from 1 to 5
            call build_number(digit_array, current_digit + 1)
        next
    end
end

call build_number(new sbyte[25], 0)
```

Please note that actually using `System.String` to store the digits would create a HUGE number of garbage strings.  It's much better to use either an array or `StringBuilder`.

Even with an efficient method of generating the strings, however, your brute-force approach is approaching in complexity the task of bruteforcing encryption using 64-bit keys, which is to say, feasible but very very lengthy.  You definitely will want to look into some tree pruning techniques.

And take advantage of the embarrassing parallelism present here.

Comment: all that recursion seems expensive.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: It isn't.  My whole solution has approximately the same cost as your step #1.  Mine also doesn't require exabytes of memory allocation for throwaway strings.

Comment: that was just a joke :-) As told above, there's no point in optimizing a run-once method.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: That depends on just how long the one run is going to take.  When the answer is *years*, and I believe that it is, spending a couple hours optimizing is well worth it.